# Failed update 14.04 server version 3.13.0-39

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I tried to upgrade my 14.04 server using `dist-upgrade`. Unfortunately the update failed and after some manual tinkering myself with broken packages I am kind of out of ideas.

I already tried to manually clean all `3.13.0-39` packages in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` and `/var/lib/dpkg/status` because no means of automatic purge/uninstall would work. After that I tried yet again to install it but unfortunately it fails with the exact same error like before:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic (3.13.0-39.66) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_XXXXXX’: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.39.46); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the output when i tried to install `linux-generic`. I have also already cleared my `/boot` of old kernels and here is an output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/duproject-root   18G  4.0G   13G  25% /
none                        4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                        991M   12K  991M   1% /dev
tmpfs                       201M  556K  200M   1% /run
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                       1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm
none                        100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                   228M   47M  170M  22% /boot
```

I am kind of out of ideas and googling only returns the standard answers anymore =/

Comment: Using `apt-get dist-upgrade` isn't really supported in Ubuntu. I personally did it when upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 (because I didn't want to install then remove Ubuntu's default packages), but I encountered many breakages along the way. Know that manually deleting `dpkg`-related files during this process isn't going to help you much.

Comment: I can determine this, though: The error occurring here is within these three lines: `mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_XXXXXX’: No such file or directory.   update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic with 1.   run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1`.

Answer (score 5):

I just got it fixed. For some unknown reason my `/var/tmp` didn't exist and my `TMPDIR` env wasn't set. This lead to initramfs to create the `mkinitramfs-FW_XXXXXX` file in `/tmp` instead but `mktemp` still looked for it in `/var/tmp`. I recrated `/var/tmp` and set `TMPDIR` and it worked like a charm =)